# Scroll to a position on scroll event

Tags: javascript, scroll

I want to implement scrolling event function that forwards me to certain position on page like it's done in FullPage.js. 
Example: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage 
I tried adding onscroll event listener, which distinguishes scrolling direction and then executes scrollTo() , but it seems like a bad idea.
How do i implement this properly? Thanks in advance.
What i tried so far:

```
    function throttle(fn, delay) {
  let last;
  let timer;

  return () => {
    const now = +new Date;

    if (last && now < last + delay) {
      clearTimeout(timer);

      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        last = now;
        fn();
      }, delay);
    } else {
      last = now;
      fn();
    }

  };
}


var scrollPos = 0;

function smooth_scroll(){
  // detects new state and compares it with the new one
  if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > scrollPos)
  {
        window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
  }
    else
  {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 1000, behavior: 'smooth' })//as an example
  }
    // saves the new position for iteration.
    scrollPos = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(smooth_scroll, 1000));
```

I expect it to work like this: whenever i scroll down it forwards me to bottom (1000, 0), and when i scroll up it gets me to the top. All smoothly.

Comment: Can you explain why scrollTo is a bad idea? Because scrollTo works pretty propperly in my opinion in this case.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag, as far as i understand each moment of scrollTo with smooth parameter counts as scrolling event, so script keeps firing again and again. I tried adding scroll throttle, but it still works weird, so idk :/

Comment: Offsite links to describe what you want to do is a bad idea, but "Its a bad idea" is not a problem statement  - please include d what you wish to achieve and the code you have tried in the question itself.

Comment: @U.Alex i see your point. The scrollTo is just a "smooth" browser specific scrolling. I postet you an explanation about how they do it and how you can implement it. If you have more questions just let me know, and I try to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look onto your example website you can see that they are not scrolling a list. They are animating a wrapper and its children:

**class: fullpage-wrapper**

```
attribute they change: transform:translate3d(0px, -937px, 0px);
```

*What happens ist that all elements are inside one wrapper which is then moved upwards the height of the box. The smooth effect of this page is provided by a specific easing which can be attached to the CSS animation.*

So if you want to get the same "scrolling" effect you need to think about an animation solution. Therefore you can stick to blank [CSS-Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) or Framework/Library specific ones.

*For further informations about animation, I can try to help you as far as it's not getting a full Animation course :)*
[image: Debugging a scroll on alvarotrigo]